# Keyframe animation issue with transform-origin

Tags: css, css-animations, css-transforms, keyframe

I'm trying to build an animation for opening a hamburger menu. I am struggling to get the hamburger to the x. In theory I seem to be doing everything right but the result tells me otherwise xD. I've been playing around with the translate values and also the transform-origin but it all behaves in (for me) unexpected ways. Could someone have a look and help me out?

My Example: https://codepen.io/aki-sol/pen/RwMoEJQ

```
<svg width="48" height="48" viewBox="0 0 48 48" fill="none" 
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <rect class="top" y="8.5" width="48" height="3.875" fill="blue" />
  <rect class="middle" y="22.0625" width="48" height="3.875" fill="blue" />
  <rect class="bottom" y="35.625" width="48" height="3.875" fill="blue" />
</svg>
```

```
svg:hover .top {
  animation-name: top;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  /*transform-origin: 25% 25%;*/
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
svg:hover .middle {
  animation-name: middle;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  transform-origin: center center;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
svg:hover .bottom {
  animation-name: bottom;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  /*transform-origin: 25% 25%;*/
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes top {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateY(30%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(45deg) translateY(-25%);
  }
}
@keyframes middle {
  50% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes bottom {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateY(-30%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
  }
}
```

Goal (first example): https://codepen.io/vineethtrv/pen/VYRzaV

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed a little bit the dimensions to make the values easier to calculate.

So, svg width is 48, so I set the transform-origin x value at 24, the center.

For top, y is 8 and height is 4, so the center is at 8 + (4 / 2) = 10.

The corrected demo goes like this:

```css
svg:hover .top {
  animation-name: top;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  transform-origin: 24px 10px;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
svg:hover .middle {
  animation-name: middle;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  transform-origin: center center;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
svg:hover .bottom {
  animation-name: bottom;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  transform-origin: 24px 38px;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes top {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateY(30%);
  }
  100% {
    transform:  translateY(30%) rotate(45deg);
  }
}
@keyframes middle {
  50% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes bottom {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateY(-30%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(-30%) rotate(-45deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<svg width="48" height="48" viewBox="0 0 48 48" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <rect class="top" y="8" width="48" height="4" fill="blue" />
  <rect class="middle" y="22" width="48" height="4" fill="blue" />
  <rect class="bottom" y="36" width="48" height="4" fill="blue" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Similar to the other answer, I don't understand why these are the right values. How did you arrive at these values? Did you just try out different values or did you deduce them from how transform-origins work?

Comment: Added an explanation in the answer.

Comment: Thanks so much for adding the explanation! I can see now how I have been approaching it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can play around with the values in the DevTools. Try nudging it with the arrow keys to get it to a position you like. I got the following:

```
svg:hover .top {
  transform-origin: 4% 28%;
}

svg:hover .bottom {
  transform-origin: 5% 50%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! It does look a lot better with those values. I just don't understand why these are the right values? These values seem to cryptic to me to represent the transform origin in the middle of the element. I know to little about svgs but I was thinking it might have something to with the composition of the svg.

Anyway, thanks a lot!

Comment: I got to those values by editing the `transform-origin` property values within the browser's developer tools. I just change them until I got the result I wanted.

Comment: I see. Thanks for explaining your process.